# Python ctypes turns every error into "free(): invalid pointer"

Tags: python, error-handling, shared-libraries, wrapper, ctypes

Dev environment:
Python 3.6
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I'm currently writing a python wrapper for a shared library using ctypes. 
The shared library is written in C++ and already has a C Wrapper:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif //__cplusplus
#define UOM_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

UOM_EXPORT MyModelInterface *createMyModel() {
    return new MyModel();
}

UOM_EXPORT int C_setOption(MyModelInterface *m, const char *option, const char *value) {
  if (m == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  m->setOption(option, value);
  return 0;
}

UOM_EXPORT int C_initializeModel(MyModelInterface *m, const char *inputFilename, float a1, float a2) {
  if (m == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  std::string input(inputFilename);
  m->initializeModel(input, a1, a2);
  return 0;
}

UOM_EXPORT int destroyMyModel(MyModelInterface *m) {
  if (m == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  delete reinterpret_cast <MyModel *>(m);
  return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif //__cplusplus
```

I created a class to act as my python interface to this C wrapper:

```
from ctypes import *

class c_model_interface(Structure):
def __init__(self):
    self._buf

class MyModel:
    library=None
    model=None

    def __init__(self,libraryPath):
        self.library=CDLL(libraryPath)
        exptr = POINTER(c_model_interface)

        self.library.createModel.restype=(exptr)
        self.library.createModel.argtypes=None

        self.library.C_initializeModel.restype=c_int
        self.library.C_initializeModel.argtypes=(exptr,c_char_p,c_float,c_float)


        self.library.C_setOption.restype=c_int
        self.library.C_setOption.argtypes=(exptr,c_char_p,c_char_p)

        voidptr = self.library.createModel()
        self.model = cast(voidptr,POINTER(c_model_interface))

    def initializeModel(self,filename,a1,a2):
        C_filename = bytes(filename,'utf8')
        C_a1 = c_float(a1)
        C_a2 = c_float(a2)
        retV = self.library.C_initializeModel(self.model,C_filename,C_a1,C_a2)
        if(retV != 0):
            raise Exception("Exception in initializeModel")

    def setOption(self,option,value):
        if not isinstance(option,str):
            raise Exception("Option needs to be a string")
        if not isinstance(value,str):
            raise Exception("Value needs to be a string")

        C_option = cast(bytes(option,'utf8'),c_char_p)
        C_value = cast(bytes(value,'utf8'),c_char_p)
        retV = self.library.C_setOption(self.model,C_option,C_value)
        if(retV != 0):
            raise Exception("Exception in setOption")

    def setOptions(self,optDict):
        for strOpt,strValue in optDict.items():
            self.setOption(strOpt,strValue)
```

It's then supposed to be called like:

```
libraryPath = "./libmymodel.so"
filename = "./test.png"
options = {"opt1":"val1","opt2":"val2"}
model = MyModel(libraryPath)
model.setOptions(options)
model.initializeModel(filename,1.0,2.0)
# ... more code
```

The code currently works. But whenever I make any mistake like typing:

```
def setOptions(self,optDict):
    for strOpt,strValue in optDict: # optDict instead of optDict.items()
        self.setOption(strOpt,strValue)
```

I get the general error:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Instead of something specific like this for the dictionary error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyModel.py", line 102, in <module>
    model.setOptions(options)
  File "MyModel.py", line 64, in setOptions
    for strOpt,strValue in optDict:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This makes debugging a nightmare. Is there any way to fix this?

EDIT: 
For a minimal example:

```
from ctypes import *

a = CDLL(mylib)
options = {"test1":1,"test2":2}

for a,b in options:
print(a,b)
```

This gives the free(): invalid pointer message, when using my own shared library as `mylib`. If I set `mylib='libc.so.6'` it correctly prints the Traceback.

EDIT2: changed the expected Traceback to be more realistic for the given example.

Comment: That's very hard to believe (with the code you posted). As a matter of fact, your code consists of segments out of which none is a minimal example (not even the one in the edit). Also where does the exception take place (which line of code)? Add the full traceback. What I can think of is that you have some free call somewhere in the lib which gets called (but again, the code doesn't show it).

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for reading the question. As I stated my problem is that I don't get a Traceback from python, even though the error is in my python code. The Traceback I quoted is a forced example. When my python code is correct the entire thing executes perfectly. But when I mistype, e.g. `optDict` instead of `optDict.items()`, the program fails with only the output `free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)` instead of the Traceback. If its any further help: the shared library I'm using is built using tensorflows C++ API which inherently uses multithreading. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Did you try `git gud`?